# QtWidget not updating when calling from another module

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a pyqt project that has a main window (main.py) with 2 tabs (view.py).  I have a button in view.py that update a title in another class (in another module).  The button seems to be executed but the title wasn't changed.  Below is the trimmed down version of the codes.

main.py

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from view import TabView


class UIWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.grid_nav = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.central_widget)
        self.grid_layout_container = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()

        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.central_widget)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(TabView().tab, "Tab1")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(TabView().tab2.tab, "Tab2")

        self.grid_layout_container.addWidget(self.tabWidget)
        self.grid_nav.addLayout(self.grid_layout_container)


    def init_window(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.resize(1158, 771)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = UIWindow()
    ui.init_window(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

view.py

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
from tab2 import Tab2


class TabView(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.tab = QtWidgets.QWidget()

        self.btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Get Data", self.tab)
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.get_data)

        self.tab2 = Tab2()
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.tab2.update_title)

    def get_data(self):
        print("blahblahblah")
```

tab2.py

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore


class Tab2(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, app):
        super().__init__(app)
        self.tab = QtWidgets.QWidget()

        self.grid_layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.tab)
        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.tab)
        self.grid_layout_frame = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.frame)

        self.title = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame)
        self.grid_layout_frame.addWidget(self.title)

    def update_title(self):
        self.title.setText("New Title") #function is called but label not updated
```

The function update_title was definitely called - if I do `print(self.title.text())`, I would see the result.  However in tabWidget, I don't see it being updated.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured out the problem.  In main.py, I was adding the tabs but with 2 instances of TabView - it should just be one.

this is the correct way,

```
self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.central_widget)
self.tab_view = TabView()
self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_view.tab, "Tab1")
self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_view.tab2.tab, "Tab2")
```